# Can you identify of the font used in the True Review's Get Instant Access button?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I looks similar to impact but not quite. I've spent like 2 hours searching and I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try What the font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your first guess was correct. It seems to be [Impact](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=G&ch%5B1%5D=&ch%5B2%5D=I&ch%5B3%5D=N&ch%5B4%5D=&ch%5B5%5D=&ch%5B6%5D=T&ch%5B7%5D=A&ch%5B8%5D=C&ch%5B9%5D=C&ch%5B10%5D=E&ch%5B11%5D=S&ch%5B12%5D=S&ch%5B13%5D=.&ch%5B14%5D=!&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=000c74da5295fe2a00027deb0000039e&glyphcount=15&imageid=0&x=56&y=39):

[image]

Comment: Yup. Looks like plain'ol Impact to me.